# Downloadable example of a normalize Inmon Enterprise Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

I am familiar with Kimball data warehouses, but I have never seen an Inmon data warehouse.  With all my research, I'm looking for a real example.  I understand that Inmon data warehouses are normalized and work with a top down approach.

Is there a downloadable example of this similar to the AdventureWorks databases that Microsoft offers?  I'm looking for how the transactional data from a OLTP database is normalized into an enterprise data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Transactional data from an OLTP data is already normalized and so the Inmon DW will look very similar to that. However the Inmon DW (or at least the ODS part of it) will be modelled independently of the OLTP system and model the business concepts, with little or no concern about things needed for OLTP transactions.
It is probably easiest to use the Adventureworks OLTP database as your template for considering this.

Comment: I hear things about Snowflake and elastic search.  Are there new data models being used in data warehousing these days outside of Inmon and Kimball?  A big advancement I think would remove the ETL work.  Has this happened yet?

Comment: You're always going to have to do some kind of work to move data about to repurpose it for different needs. What changes are the technologies for storage and the best styles for doing stuff with it, like ELT rather than ETL, loading to blobs, etc. There are new approaches and technologies but they aim for something different to the central, quality data store espoused by Inmon and kimball. Check out data vault for further learning